# Way to click two different place simultaneously in the screen on OS X

Tags: macos, testing, web, click, mouse

I'm working on testing a web application where I need to click two different places in the screen
simultaneously (or in milliseconds delay) but I couldn't find any solution to it. How can I do that? I'm using OS X 10.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your looked at AppleScript or Automator?
I've used both, and Automator can record exactly what you do on screen, then you can adjust the timing.